# amsmath: request improved formatting to display an exponent multiplied by a fractional exponent

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath, fractions

The mwe rendering for the distribution of a fractional exponent to a single digit exponent (basically a power to another power) is shown here:

[image]

To my eyes, the multiplication in the exponent seems a bit hard to read. Is there a better formatting solution?

Also, what in my code is causing the **enumeration to be bold**?

Thanks very much for your assistance!

mwe

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Unit 13 A\&B Fractional Exponents}
       {}
       {Due 05/02/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
%\noindent 
\bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    label-format = \bfseries, % numbers in bold added <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}

\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
%%
%%%% Prob #16
\task
$(a^3b^5)^{1/6}$
\begin{solutionorbox}[5cm]
$(a^{3\bm{\cdot}1/6})(b^{5\bm{\cdot}1/6})$
\bigskip
$(a^{1/2})(b^{5/6})$
\bigskip
\colorbox{yellow}{$\sqrt{a}\sqrt[6]{b^5}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}
%%
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A small improvement would be to make the two radicals the same height,  To do that, inside the first, add `\vphantom{b}`.

Comment: Regarding the bold, that's what you've asked for: in `\settasks`, you have `label-format = \bfseries`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  That's what I get for copying code from another project. Thanks very much for educating me about the ```label-format=\bfseries```. Step by small step, thanks to generous folks like you, I'm learning the effect of each code line. Thank you!

Comment: @barbarabeeton When I replaced ```\bfseries``` with ```\series```, overleaf kicked out this error: ```control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.``` What did I do wrong in trying to remove the bold from the enumeration?

Comment: There isn't any command that's just plain `\series`.  I'm not really familiar with the tasks package, but I'd try just commenting out the `label-format` line.  (That would make the assumption that the default is lightface roman.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks very much! As you suggested, commenting out the ```label-format``` line solves the problem.